# Find the text of an LI in an on click event using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, this

I am trying to find the text of an LI item using (this).text() but it tells me it doesn't have the text method. How can i refer to the text in the LI?

```
$('.mylist').on('click','li',function() {alert('fired '+(this).text());});

<body>
  <ul class=mylist>The unordered list
    <li id=one>test one</li>
    <li id=two>test two</li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

The bin is http://jsbin.com/IKiZOmA/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$(this).text()` instead of `(this).text()`

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes. 
id and classes should be in " "

```
<ul class="mylist">The unordered list
    <li id="one">test one</li>
    <li id="two">test two</li>
  </ul>
```

`this` changed to `$(this)`

```
{alert('fired '+($(this).text()));});
```